# (Automation: Appium\Java) (Xamarin Forms\iOS 13) Elements not visible in tree, after in-app downloads

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, appium-ios

**Summary:** We have a Xaamrin Forms iOS\Android application. My goal is to make auto-tests for iOS-app built with Xamarin.IOS 12.10 and Xcode 10.2.1. Builds are made by App Center. Target iOS versions are: 12 and 13. Testing must be performed on real devices, so I not bothered with simulators.

**Problem:** on devices with iOS 13 element tree contains all elements correctly, i.e. Appium can see all elements and interact with them. But, after "synchronisation" (Which is in-app download of database from server. It's necessary for application to work) element tree reduces just for 2-3, each representing a whole screen. So tests cannot find particular elements and fail. Strangely, but on iOS 12 things go smooth all time whether app made download or not.

**Appium versions used:**
1.15.1 - on local machine,
1.11 in App Center (though I suppose they've forked it somehow, but it never explicitly said in documentation)
Problem oсcured on both versions.

**Questions:** How elements can become inaccessible like so in general? What is most probable source of problem in this case particular: iOS, Appium, maybe app itself? Did someone encaunter this or a similar problem? Is there a working solution for it?

Here are links to page sources that I managed to get from tests. I got theese two from same device iPhone XR, iOS 13.3, Appium 1.15.1

Normal Element Tree: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G82n1xYAxiMQ3q-VV22NXCarM_2dXws3

Element Tree After DB Download: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nywD3ShSdb1lDbN77mGB6WW018RNjO4F

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its an issue with how Appium is loading the accessibility id's. if you turn on VoiceOver the inspector can again see them. There is an open bug on Xamarin GitHub related to this. [Xamarin Forms iOS issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6667)

[image]

Comment: this bug was closed on Xamarin's GitHub. the fix was only partial though as it fixed accessibility ID"s but not xpath. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6667